# Error after adding a repository in build.grade

Tags: android, github, repository, build.gradle

I am adding a repository in my build.grade but as soon as I click "sync now" It shows errors:

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1
>       Install Repository and sync project
> Open File
> Show in Project Structure 
>       dialog
>       Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1
>       Install Repository and sync project
>       Open File
> Show in Project Structure 
>       dialog

This is the repository I am trying to add

```
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.7'
```

My build.grade(Module:app)

```
ext{
supportVersion = "26.0.0-alpha1"
   }

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
     core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-
    annotations'
     })
     compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportVersion}"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportVersion}"
    compile 'com.simplecityapps:recyclerview-fastscroll:1.0.16'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:${supportVersion}"
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.7'
    }
```

After removing the repository which I am trying to add I don't get any errors.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope to use full

```
 repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
```